# How do we consider the 'content' of a statement in propositional logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

From what I understand about formal logic, we are not concerned with the statements' content or our intuitive understanding of the content for that matter, but we are concerned with the statement forms or the way that the statements relate to each other.

Now please take a look at the picture taken from a book: (Discrete Maths & Its Applications by Susanna)
[image]

In the highlighted portions, the author is asserting that the statements are true or false based on the content alone. She is using the content's understanding of numbers to determine the truth values.

But isn't it against the principal of formal logic? I mean we can not determine the truth values or derive conclusions based on the content, right?

Please explain what is happening here.

Comment: To show that two statements are not logically equivalent, it suffices to show there is an interpretation of the letters that gives the statements different truth values. In this case, the authors are giving $p$ the truth value “true” and $q$ the truth value “false,” and then showing that the two statements under consideration come out to have different truth values. That is all that matters. It does not matter what true statement you assign: it could be “$0<1$,” or “‘gnft’ is not an English word,” or “the moon is not made of green cheese” — so you might as well just think of assigning “true.”

Comment: It is only a didactical approach: you can use instead truth tables to check that with $p$ TRUE and $q$ FALSE we have that $\lnot (p \land q)$ is TRUE while $\lnot p \land \lnot q$ is FALSE. Thus, the two are not logically equiv.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Understood. And I am absolutely right to assume that formal logic does not take the 'content' or its intuitive meaning into consideration, right?

Comment: Note, these arguments are using a meta-theorem about the logical system: that it is sound. So logically equivalent propositions have the same truth value for all valuations. The contrapositive of soundness means that if you can find valuations that give the propositions different truth values, they are not logically equivalent. Ideally, the book would be a bit more explicit about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notion of "content" in propositional calculus is formalized with that of [interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Interpretation_of_a_truth-functional_propositional_calculus) :

> An interpretation of a truth-functional propositional calculus $\mathcal {P}$ is an assignment to each propositional symbol of the language of $\mathcal {P}$ of one or the other (but not both) of the truth values truth (T) and falsity (F), and an assignment to the connective symbols of $\mathcal {P}$ of their usual truth-functional meanings.
>
> An interpretation of a truth-functional propositional calculus may also be expressed in terms of truth tables.

Thus, *logical equivalence* formalize the property of "having the same content".

Comment: @ParkerQueen - I'm not saying that; the concept of "logical equiv" applies to formulas, like e.g. $p \lor q$. A statement of natural language is not usually "subject to different interpretations".

Comment: @ParkerQueen - we can check with truth table that $\lnot (p \land q)$ is logically equiv to $\lnot p \lor \lnot q$.